# 2.8 beta - How to hide HDRI in EEVEE?

Tags: 3d-view

I know how to get a transparent background for a render in EEVEE and I also know about the lightpath node trick to hide it.

However it seems like there should be a simple checkbox to disable it in the viewport on rendered preview. Am I missing something?

Comment: Light Path is your only way. There is no simple checkbox. You can hide/change background in lookdev and such but not in EEVEE.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the light path node to achieve this:

[image]

As you can see, it's showing up in reflections, but for the camera it just displays the other background shader. This also works for cycles.

Answer (score 0):

Can’t you just set the strenght at zero in the world properties panel? Then there is no more HDR background and lighting. Or disconnect the output node of the world settings in the (node)shader editor?

Comment: I want the lighting from the HDRI but I don't want the HDRI to show in the background.